# Feature Scaling in Regression

Tags: regression, normalization, gradient-descent, feature-scaling

I have a dataset in which each sample has only two features. I designed my own gradient descent algorithm, and applied it to my dataset. However, I could not obtain a result. Then, I printed the parameters generated during gradient descent, and I realized that `zigzagging` happens. In other words, the algorithm cannot converge to optimum point due to the value ranges that my features vary in. My features have very different value ranges.

Then, I performed mean normalization operation for feature scaling to my dataset and trained my data. My gradient descent algorithm worked perfectly well. It converged very quickly. After that, I trained another model by using built-in scikit LinearRegression library to check the success of my gradient descent algorithm. Both models, first of which is trained by my gradient descent and second of which is trained by `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, make very close predictions. As a result, my algorithm works properly.

The problematic issue is the values of parameters which are slope m and bias value b in the equation `mx +b`. Since I performed mean normalization to the features of my data set, feature space is changed. `Hence, parameter values that I obtain at the end of my gradient descent and the parameter values that built-in acquire at the end of the training are not same.`

`Is it possible to track original parameters even if feature scaling is performed ?`

I provided equation of mean normalization that I performed below:

$x^{new} = \frac{x - u}{max(x) - min(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to always use this scalling for your futures (also form the test set) if you want to run a prediction, the value xnew will always between (0,1) so I should not be a problem for your prediction. But don't normalize your prediction value, this is not needed.